# Sweet-Captcha Security Vulnerability

Tags: security, captcha

We've recently started using the user-friendly website captcha [sweet-captcha](http://sweetcaptcha.com/) on our websites. After a recent round of security audits we found a potential vulnerability.

*This vulnerability allows an attacker to circumvent the captcha indefinitely after one successful solve.*

I've tried contacting the captcha creators regarding this but have not had any response. I am posting here primarily in the hope that my implementation is incorrect and as such a more secure alternative is immediately available.

The captcha is included in our pages, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/sweetcaptcha/sweetcaptcha-sdk-php/blob/master/example.php):

```
<?php echo $sweetcaptcha->get_html() ?>
```

Most of our websites are DHTML to avoid reloading which is what made us aware of the security issue as follows:

1. Someone solves the captcha and submits an ajax request to our php web service which includes the necessary captcha keys.
2. The web service validates the captcha as per the documentation (see `$sweetcaptcha->check` below), performs some work and then returns its response to the front end.
3. As the front end is not refreshed, and thus the captcha remains solved, it has become apparent that the same captcha keys can be used again to make as many requests as desired following an initial successful solve.

**To solve this security problem we believe the following step should be occurring:**

Invalidate the captcha response in the php web service to prevent an individual using the same captcha tokens more than one, e.g. if a call too:

```
$sweetcaptcha->check(array('sckey' => $_POST['sckey'], 'scvalue' => $_POST['scvalue']))
```

returns true, it should return false on all subsequent evaluations using the same parameters. That is not happening. Even though we could implement our own backend solution to prevent duplicate validations this would be best solved in the captchas existing code if it should be the case.

If anyone could advise on the above issue that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have heard back from the developers. According to them this issue has now been resolved (not tested).

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html